# Error : ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'. > java.io.FileNotFoundException: BuildConfig.java

Tags: java, android

I get this error when I open the project in android studio:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'.
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\NEW\Gravity Adventure Falls\Code
>   source\android2\app\build\generated\source\buildConfig\debug\com\Gravity\Adventure\BuildConfig.java 
>   (The system cannot find the path specified)

Answer (score 5):

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\devloper\Desktop\android 
studoi\app\build\generated\source\buildConfig\debug\com\yourname\IceClimber 
\BuildConfig.java (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Check your package name, if it has any space between package name eg. if your package name is com.example.yourapp if you have any space between inverted commas eg : " com.yourname.nameapp" and check your package name in your gradle too "com.yourname.nameapp "

Answer (score 3):

The error you have got is simple to fix go to manifiest file and check you package name check has any space between package name eg if your package name is com.example.yourapp  if you have any space between inverted commas eg :    **" com.example.yourapp"** or  go to project settings and check the package name correctly mention without spaces.